# React / How to show details for each item Im iterating through onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am iterating and rendering multiple products. I can see the details for each product onclick. The way I have it now, when I press lets say on product2 and I have in total 5 products, all products will show details for product2. How can I change my code to make it work? Thanks!

```
const App = () => {
    const {state: {isFetchingDetailsForProduct, detailsForProduct}, fetchDetailsForProduct} = useContext(SearchContext);
    
    const getDetails = async (product) => {
        await fetchDetailsForProduct(product) //api call to fetch details for chosen product
    };
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
                return (
                    <Product
                        product={item}
                        getDetails={getDetails}
                        details={detailsForProduct}
                        isFetching={isFetchingDetailsForProduct}
                    />
                )
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        />
    )
}

const Product = ({getDetails, product, details, isFetching}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <ListItem.Accordion
                content={
                    <>
                        <ListItem>
                            <View>
                                <Text>{product.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </ListItem>
                    </>
                }
                isExpanded={expanded}
                onPress={() => {
                    setExpanded(!expanded);
                    getDetails(product.name)
                }}
            >
                    <Details
                        isFetching={isFetching}
                        details={details} //here if I have 3 products, I pass 3 x same details for product1 (or whichever clicked) to all
                    />
            </ListItem.Accordion>
        </>
    )
};
```

the products and their details come from different collections (seems weird, but has a reason).

const data = [{name: "product1", category: "abc",...}, {},...];
const details = [{product. "product1", color: "red",...},{},...]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are fetching the product details of specific product, you have to update the product details in data array.
example:

```
data = [{name: 'Product1', details: null}, {name: 'Product2', details: null}]
```

when i click on Product1 api call gives me result update the data as below

```
data = [{name: 'Product1', details: [...apiResponse]}, {name: 'Product2', details: null}]
```

and Render the data appropriately

OR

```
<FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
                return (
                    <Product
                        product={item}
                        getDetails={getDetails}
                        details={data.find(x => x.name === detailsForProduct.productName)}
                        isFetching={isFetchingDetailsForProduct}
                    />
                )
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        />
```

Comment: I should have maybe added this to my question, the details are not in data. Its coming from a different collection so i m fetching that separatly. I updated my question

Comment: still you can add details in data array, you must be fetching details based on product name, on success of api find the product and add the details

Comment: no i cannot in my case just add the detailed into the data, so i must find another solution.

Comment: also, I only want to fetch the details onclick (like in my code). if I added it somehow to the data, then i would have to fetch all the details for all products upfront which i do not want.

Comment: its not necessary to fetch all the details upfront, just fetch the data on onClick and put a check if current product already has details don’t fetch it

Comment: but my problem is when I fetch onclick, since im iterating through all products, i pass the same details of item x  I fetched to all items

Comment: yeah that's why i am saying you need to pass details specific to product, either add the detail in data or while showing details put condition based on productName